# Loading em cima do mapa

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps

Tenho o seguinte código desenhado 2 polígonos no mapa. Veja:

```js
function initialize() {
  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var i;

  var polygonCoords = [
     new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
     new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
     new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.757370)
  ];
  

  for (i = 0; i < polygonCoords.length; i++) {
     bounds.extend(polygonCoords[i]);
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: bounds.getCenter(),
    mapTypeId: "roadmap"
  });


  var triangle1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: polygonCoords,
    strokeColor: '#0000ff',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#0000ff',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  triangle1.setMap(map);
  
  var polygonCoords2 = [
     new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
     new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
     new google.maps.LatLng(14.979063, -83.500871)
  ];

  var triangule2 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: polygonCoords2,
    strokeColor: '#0000ff',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#0000ff',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  triangule2.setMap(map);
  
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.loader{
 margin:100px auto;
}
h1{
 font-family: 'Actor', sans-serif;
 color:#000;
 font-size:16px;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 font-weight:200;
 text-align:center;
}
.loader span{
 width:16px;
 height:16px;
 border-radius:50%;
 display:inline-block;
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 margin-left:-10px;
 -webkit-animation:3s infinite linear;
 -moz-animation:3s infinite linear;
 -o-animation:3s infinite linear;
 
}


.loader span:nth-child(2){
 background:#E84C3D;
 -webkit-animation:kiri 1.2s infinite linear;
 -moz-animation:kiri 1.2s infinite linear;
 -o-animation:kiri 1.2s infinite linear;
 
}
.loader span:nth-child(3){
 background:#F1C40F;
 z-index:100;
}
.loader span:nth-child(4){
 background:#2FCC71;
 -webkit-animation:kanan 1.2s infinite linear;
 -moz-animation:kanan 1.2s infinite linear;
 -o-animation:kanan 1.2s infinite linear;
}


@-webkit-keyframes kanan {
    0% {-webkit-transform:translateX(20px);
    }
   
 50%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-20px);
 }
 
 100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(20px);
 z-index:200;
 }
}
@-moz-keyframes kanan {
    0% {-moz-transform:translateX(20px);
    }
   
 50%{-moz-transform:translateX(-20px);
 }
 
 100%{-moz-transform:translateX(20px);
 z-index:200;
 }
}
@-o-keyframes kanan {
    0% {-o-transform:translateX(20px);
    }
   
 50%{-o-transform:translateX(-20px);
 }
 
 100%{-o-transform:translateX(20px);
 z-index:200;
 }
}




@-webkit-keyframes kiri {
     0% {-webkit-transform:translateX(-20px);
 z-index:200;
    }
 50%{-webkit-transform:translateX(20px);
 }
 100%{-webkit-transform:translateX(-20px);
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes kiri {
     0% {-moz-transform:translateX(-20px);
 z-index:200;
    }
 50%{-moz-transform:translateX(20px);
 }
 100%{-moz-transform:translateX(-20px);
 }
}
@-o-keyframes kiri {
     0% {-o-transform:translateX(-20px);
 z-index:200;
    }
 50%{-o-transform:translateX(20px);
 }
 100%{-o-transform:translateX(-20px);
 }
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<body onload="initialize()">
 
  <div class="loader">
    <h1>CARREGANDO</h1>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>  
</div>
 <div id="map_canvas2" style="height: 100vh; width:100vw"></div>
</body>
```

Gostaria que o *load* permanecesse em cima do mapa até seu carregamento ou por um tempo fixo, por exemplo uns 5 segundos.

Qual seria melhor forma de fazer isso?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se é a melhor forma, pois utilizei o css para posicionar o loader em cima do mapa, *talvez* possa existir alguma forma nativa do google maps para adicionar um loader.

Adicionei a chamada para o evento [tilesloaded](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference?hl=pt-br) que é executado quando o mapa carrega, através de pesquisas e testes vi que o evento [idle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference?hl=pt-br) também poderia ser utilizado neste caso.

Nota é necessário usar o método [`addListenerOnce`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference), para garantir que o código seja executado uma vez apenas.

Deixei o tempo fixo em 5 segundos, após o mapa ser carregado, espera 5 segundos e esconde o `.loader`.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".loader").css("display", "none");
    }, 5000);
 });
```

```js
function initialize() {
  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var i;

  var polygonCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.757370)
  ];


  for (i = 0; i < polygonCoords.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(polygonCoords[i]);
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: bounds.getCenter(),
    mapTypeId: "roadmap"
  });


  var triangle1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: polygonCoords,
    strokeColor: '#0000ff',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#0000ff',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  triangle1.setMap(map);

  var polygonCoords2 = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
    new google.maps.LatLng(14.979063, -83.500871)
  ];

  var triangule2 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: polygonCoords2,
    strokeColor: '#0000ff',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#0000ff',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  triangule2.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".loader").css("display", "none");
      $(".divFundo").css("display", "none");
    }, 5000);
  });

}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.loaderPosition {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 45%;
}

.loader {
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.divFundo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.4;
  z-index: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Actor', sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
}

.loader span {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  -webkit-animation: 3s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: 3s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: 3s infinite linear;
}

.loader span:nth-child(2) {
  background: #E84C3D;
  -webkit-animation: kiri 1.2s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: kiri 1.2s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: kiri 1.2s infinite linear;
}

.loader span:nth-child(3) {
  background: #F1C40F;
  z-index: 100;
}

.loader span:nth-child(4) {
  background: #2FCC71;
  -webkit-animation: kanan 1.2s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: kanan 1.2s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: kanan 1.2s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes kanan {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
    z-index: 200;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes kanan {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(20px);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(20px);
    z-index: 200;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes kanan {
  0% {
    -o-transform: translateX(20px);
  }
  50% {
    -o-transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: translateX(20px);
    z-index: 200;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes kiri {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
    z-index: 200;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes kiri {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-20px);
    z-index: 200;
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(20px);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes kiri {
  0% {
    -o-transform: translateX(-20px);
    z-index: 200;
  }
  50% {
    -o-transform: translateX(20px);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<body onload="initialize()">
  <div class="divFundo"></div>
  <div class="loaderPosition">
    <div class="loader">
      <h1>CARREGANDO</h1>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="map_canvas2" style="height: 100vh; width:100vw"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Deu certinho! Vlw+1

Answer (score 1):

Eu atribui `position:absolute` nas divs loader, assim ele irá sobrepor o restante, posicionei MANUALMENTE escolhendo o top e left da div e setei o index-z em 1 para ele sobrepor o canvas.

Para verificar se o mapa foi carregado, eu pesquisei [nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228958/how-to-check-if-google-maps-api-is-loaded) e obtive isso: `(typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object')`. Sendo assim fiz um while que verifica se `loaded = true` enquanto for falso, não irá fazer nada, quando se tornar true, ele irá dar um show off na div fazendo o loader desaparecer.

```js
   
function initialize() {
  // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var i;

  var polygonCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.321384, -64.757370)
  ];


  for (i = 0; i < polygonCoords.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(polygonCoords[i]);
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas2"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: bounds.getCenter(),
    mapTypeId: "roadmap"
  });


  var triangle1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: polygonCoords,
    strokeColor: '#0000ff',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#0000ff',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  triangle1.setMap(map);

  var polygonCoords2 = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(25.774252, -80.190262),
    new google.maps.LatLng(18.466465, -66.118292),
    new google.maps.LatLng(14.979063, -83.500871)
  ];

  var triangule2 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: polygonCoords2,
    strokeColor: '#0000ff',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#0000ff',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
  triangule2.setMap(map);
  
  var Loaded = false;
  $(".loader *").show();
  
  while(!Loaded){
  
       Loaded = (typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object');

       if(Loaded){
        $(".loader *").hide();
       }
  }

 
}
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.loader {
  margin: 100px auto;
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top:10px;
  left:200px
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Actor', sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
}

.loader span {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
  -webkit-animation: 3s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: 3s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: 3s infinite linear;
}

.loader span:nth-child(2) {
  background: #E84C3D;
  -webkit-animation: kiri 1.2s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: kiri 1.2s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: kiri 1.2s infinite linear;
}

.loader span:nth-child(3) {
  background: #F1C40F;
  z-index: 100;
}

.loader span:nth-child(4) {
  background: #2FCC71;
  -webkit-animation: kanan 1.2s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: kanan 1.2s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: kanan 1.2s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes kanan {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
    z-index: 200;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes kanan {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(20px);
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(20px);
    z-index: 200;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes kanan {
  0% {
    -o-transform: translateX(20px);
  }
  50% {
    -o-transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: translateX(20px);
    z-index: 200;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes kiri {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
    z-index: 200;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(20px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes kiri {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-20px);
    z-index: 200;
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(20px);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes kiri {
  0% {
    -o-transform: translateX(-20px);
    z-index: 200;
  }
  50% {
    -o-transform: translateX(20px);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: translateX(-20px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<body onload="initialize()">

  <div class="loader">
    <h1>CARREGANDO</h1>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  <div id="map_canvas2" style="height: 100vh; width:100vw">
  <div class="loader">
    <h1>CARREGANDO</h1>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```